# Case-insensitive Comparator breaks my TreeMap

Tags: java, comparator

A `Comparator` I used in my `TreeMap` broke the behavior I intended for that `TreeMap`. Look at the following code:

```
TreeMap<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.toLowerCase());
    }
});
treeMap.put("abc", "Element1");
treeMap.put("ABC", "Element2");
```

What I think I have done is that I have created a map that is sorted by its keys, case-insensitive. The two distinct elements have non-equal keys (`abc` and `ABC`) whose comparison will return `0`. I expected just a random ordering of the two elements. Yet, the command:

```
System.out.println("treeMap: " + treeMap);
```

resulted in:

```
treeMap: {abc=Element2}
```

The key `abc` has been re-assigned the value `Element2`!

Can anyone explain how could this happen and if it's a valid, documented behavior of `TreeMap`?

Comment: `Comparator` is a *total order*. What does it even mean for "abc" and "ABC" to be in your map? Which comes first?

Comment: you got your intended (if unexpected) behaviour; your comparator is case-insensitive, your map uses that comparator - so it is also, by extension, case-insensitive (w.r.t. keys). *You just figured how to make map that's case-insensitive* - kudos to you, but I see nothing "shocking" or "illegal" here... it's doing exactly what you *told* it to do.

Comment: related: [Java TreeMap custom comparator weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219835/java-treemap-custom-comparator-weird-behaviour)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It happens because `TreeMap` considers elements equal if `a.compareTo(b) == 0`. It's documented in [the JavaDoc for TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) (emphasis mine):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, **must be consistent with `equals`** if this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface. (See `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a precise definition of consistent with `equals`.) This is so because the Map interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so **two keys that are deemed equal by this method are**, from the standpoint of the sorted map, **equal**. The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with `equals`; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface.

Your comparator isn't consistent with equals.

If you want to keep not-equal-but-equal-ignoring-case elements, put a second level of checking into your comparator, to use case-sensitive ordering:

```
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int cmp = o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        if (cmp != 0) return cmp;

        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, guys, for quick answers! Now I see it stated clearly in the docs, though I still consider this behavior counterintuitive on the Java side. After all, TreeMap is for sorting, and sorting is probably most often performed on texts in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: @javaxian TreeMap is for maintaining items in a map backed by a tree, the sorting is more of a side effect of tree usage. But yes, it is counterintuitive because it violates the guarantees of the Map interface. Not very nice of the Java devs.

Comment: @JAB: I'm not sure that I agree. The `TreeMap` class adheres to the guarantees of the `Map` interface, provided that you adhere to the guarantees of its interface! Its documentation clearly states the comparator must be consistent with `equals`. Similarly, any `HashMap` will misbehave if `equals` and `hashCode` are not consistent—do you also think that this is "not very nice"? My point is: contracts go both ways.

Comment: @wchargin that behavior of `HashMap` *isn't* very nice, simply because it puts the onus on the user to do it right. We could have checks everywhere for consistency (similarly to "comparator violates general contract"); but the additional cost of these checks is unnecessary if you've read the docs and implemented the comparator accordingly. (I agree with your comment, BTW)

Comment: I have to admit, it would be convenient to annotate properties as `Identifiable` and then have equals, hashcode, and compareTo be calculated automatically by those (obviously compare to would need to know the order in which to compare them) - yes you need the ability to do it the old fashioned way, but let's face it, in 99% of cases, hashcode and equals only ever use one or two fields.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I mean that it's not nice that the consistency can't be automatically enforced by the compiler. It would be *hard* for the compiler to do that, but I bet that such enforcement would have saved an awful lot of stress and heartache over the years.

Answer (score 12):

The `Comparator` you pass to a `TreeMap` determines not just the ordering of the keys inside the `Map`, it also determines whether two keys are considered identical (they are considered identical when `compare()` returns `0`).

Therefore, in your `TreeMap`, "abc" and "ABC" are considered identical keys. `Map`s don't allow identical keys, so the second value `Element2` overwrites the first value `Element1`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure that the equality of that map's elements is consistent with the comparator. Quoting from the class comment:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map,
>   and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be
>   consistent with equals if this sorted map is to correctly
>   implement the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is technically correct, but misses the idiomatic solution to the problem.

You should be using the static [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) comparator provided or at least using [`String.compareToIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) inside your own to consider what is `.equal()`.

For locale sensitive comparisons, you should use something from [`java.text.Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html)

Comment: It’s correct that developers should use existing comparators or use dedicated comparison methods instead of the expensive “convert to lowercase” anti-pattern. But it doesn't solve the problem. You still need a two step comparator. The Java 8 solution would be `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`.

Comment: @AndyTurner you're absolutely right about using built-in comparators (or a Collator in this case) rather than writing my own ones. In my production code, however, I was comparing objects using their presentationOrder integer fields that had the same value in some cases. I didn't want to make my example here overly complex, so I went with a case-insensitive String comparator.